# Synopsys Synplify Pro synthesis failed when using "``"

Tags: verilog, synthesis, xilinx-ise, synplify

When I try to use construction like this my synthesis was failed

```
`define defLOMIC 0 //For example
`define rd(LOMIC) `def``LOMIC
```

Late:

```
wire lod = `rd(LOMIC);
```

Error:

```
E   CS231   Unknown macro def   VDF_TOP.v (368) syntax.log (13) 09:14:32 Thu Dec 06 Synthesis Check
E   CS234   expecting identifier immediately following back-quote (`)   VDF_TOP.v (368) syntax.log (14) 09:14:32 Thu Dec 06 Synthesis Check
```

If I use ISE XST for this, the synthesis goes well.

Used "Synplify C-2009.06"

Does anyone know maybe "``" is not supported? How to enable it? Or in which version is support it?

Comment: why is this tagged with VHDL?

Comment: you are abusing macro resolution language :-). can you switch to something more recent? your tool is about 10 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'``' is a SystemVerilog construct. Change your file extension to *.sv. Or use the -sysv switch. It's possible 2009 is too old a version.

Comment: Yes, I just switch on SV support, I can't change * .v to * .sv as I’ll probably lose syntax highlighting in ISE.